# refetchevent fullcalendar not working or dont know where to call

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am calling after ajax event but not getting any data updation on calendar:
for example: if I am making date from 10 to 12 then after calling refetchevent it should show me colored event from 10 to till 12 but it remain on 10 and not moving.

Js code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ //re-initialize the calendar
            header: h,
            defaultView: 'month', // change default view with available options from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/ 
            slotMinutes: 15,
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!

            drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
                var drop_d = date.getDate();
                var drop_m = date.getMonth();
                var drop_m = drop_m + 1;
                var drop_y = date.getFullYear();
                var init_zero = "";
                if(drop_d >= 1 && drop_d <= 9) {
                    var init_zero = "0";

                } else {
                    var init_zero = "";

                }
                if(drop_m >= 1 && drop_m <= 9) {
                    var month_zero = "0";

                } else {
                    var month_zero = "";

                }
                var drop_date = init_zero + drop_d + "/" + month_zero + drop_m + "/" + drop_y;
                //alert(originalEventObject.title);
                var caller = "1";
                //alert(drop_date);
                //here add call to the lightbox.....to fill the information....
                $.ajax({
                    url: "vehicle_driver_bookwindow.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {driver_name: originalEventObject.title, dropped_on_date: drop_date, caller_from: caller },
                    success: function(data) {
                        document.getElementById("bookwindow").innerHTML = data;
                        ComponentsPickers.init();
                        $("#a_bookwindow").click();

                    }


                });


                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                copiedEventObject.className = $(this).attr("data-class");

                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);


                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            },
            /*eventSources: [

    // your event source
    {
        url: "<?php include 'vehicle_json.php'; ?>", // use the `url` property
    }

    // any other sources...

],*/
        //events: 'vehicle_json.php',
            events: <?php include 'vehicle_json.php'; ?>,
            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
```

and following where I am trying to call again events to display events again with refresh.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "save_booking_details.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {booking_id: bookingid},
    success: function(data){
        //alert(data);
        //location.reload();

        //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', curSource[0]);
    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', curSource[0]);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

& its not working can someone tell me what I am missing or where I am wrong...

MY JSON PHP FILE:

> ```
> <?php
>                   $driver_booking = q("select * from vehicle_driver_booking where vehicle_id = ".$_REQUEST['ch']);
>                   $array = array();
>                   foreach($driver_booking as $bookings) {
>                       $driver = getR("vehicle_driver", $bookings['driver_id']);
>                       //return date_time from only....
>                       $date_from = date("Y-m-d",$bookings['datetime_from']);
>                       $time_from = date("H:i:s",$bookings['datetime_from']);
>                       //return date_time to only.....
>                       $date_to = date("Y-m-d",$bookings['datetime_to']);
>                       $time_to = date("H:i:s",$bookings['datetime_to']);
>                       if($bookings['days_option'] == 1) {
>                           $start = $date_from."T".$time_from;
>                           $array[] = array('id' => $bookings['id'], 'title' => $driver['name'], 'start' => $start, 'allDay' => false);
>                       } else {
>                           $start = $date_from."T".$time_from;
>                           $end = $date_to."T".$time_to;
>                           $array[] = array('id' => $bookings['id'], 'title' => $driver['name'], 'start' => $start, 'end' => $end, 'allDay' => false);
>                       }
>
>                   }
>
>                   echo json_encode($array);
>               ?>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are including `vehicle_json.php` file in your script. Rather than including the file pass the `url` instead.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/vehicle_json.php',//place your relevant url here
});
```

`refetchEvents` Refetches events from all sources and rerenders them on the screen and you are just passing an `json` data from your file `vehicle_json.php`

Comment: Hi, its not working if I make vehicle_json.php then and if I do include vehicle_json.php then it work so someone tell me where I am making mistake

Comment: paste your json response and see on console if ajax is fired properly